# SQL check if between daterange exceeds the limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

In my current stored procedure, I am taking data from both Current data table and Archive data table, where I "union all" Select statements from both sources.

However, the procedure takes a long time to execute, so I was thinking of ways to optimize the performance. In my case, I decided to do a conditional check if Archived data exists or not.

For my case, the data is archived if it exceeds 45-day limit from current day.

To make things simple, below are 2 simplified cases. If the user selects the current month (May in our case and 05/02 is a current day), the daterange would be only in current dataset since we did not break 45-day limit yet (between 05/01 and 05/31). Same goes for April (daterange between 04/01 and 04/30), since it's 30 days are still in 45-day limit + 2 days from May.

However, it the user chooses March on the current day, some of its days will go over the limit of 45 days (daterange between 03/01 and 03/31), and that is the case where I will need to look into archived data and union all with current data.

My questions is the following: **What is the best way to check if the daterange exceeds n-day limit?**

Comment: Are you referring to something like this?
 IF DATEADD(day,-45, DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) > @StartParam 
Query with union
Else
Query without Union

Comment: Is there any date filtering on the part of the SP that queries the archive database?

Comment: @DanBracuk Not really, I have written an SP where 1 day worth of data is moved from Current into Archived as the day ends.

Comment: @KevinJohnson Pretty much, and you might just have given me the idea...

Comment: I see you say March might be out of reach so assuming 45 days of both future and pas then this should work I think this is what you want.
select case when Square(DATEDIFF(DAY, Cast('05/02/2017' as date), Cast('03/30/2017' as date))) < Square(45) then 'Within 45 date range' else 'Outside 45 date rang' end  --- Squaring is done to remove negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If things are that simple you could use [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

```
IF DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, GETDATE()) < 45
BEGIN
    -- Pseudo query
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE CreatedAt > @StartDate;
END;
ELSE
    -- Another pseudo query
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE CreatedAt > @StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Archive.Table
    WHERE CreatedAt > @StartDate;
END;
```

Ultimately, if you'd like to avoid conditional statements, I'd say you could create a covering index on your archive table (I'm not sure how big is it) where your timestamp would be first key. Having that SQL Server would seek through that index efficiently and your code would be easier to maintain and read.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Archive.Table
    ) AS T
WHERE T.CreatedAt > @StartDate;
```

In order to speed up performance even more. You could add a constraint to your archive table, such as:

```
ALTER TABLE Archive.Table
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ArchiveTable_CreatedAt CHECK (DATEDIFF(DAY, CreatedAt, GETDATE()) < 45);
```

This should give a hint for SQL Server not to query this table if your `@StartDate` is less than 45 days. Keep in mind that this could be rewritten using [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql). It could be more efficient.

Comment: I actually started to think around your first statement logic, just in different wording. I will also try out your other 2 suggestions, but that is an answer for me. Thank you.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok yep, there is nothing wrong with conditional statements, but I prefer pretty code. Let me know if other two solutions worked for you. I'm curious.